# centering a div content inside a column in bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im new to bootstrap and im having trouble for days now to center some content inside a column in bootstrap. i want to center that circle which is above the text and i want it to stay centered in all browser sizes (responsive). i tried hundreds of solutions but none worked. pls anyone help
 below is the codepen link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaQvVE

and some code as stackoverflow suggested (the html):

```
    <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 logo"> 

        <div class="star">
</div>
<div class="moon center-block">
</div>
<div class="moon2 center-block">
</div>
              </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

                </div>

        </div>


        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 

        <div class="logo-text">UMBRA</div>

                </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

                </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You want it below the text in the same position as the text or you want it on the left of the text and aligned vertically in the middle ?

Comment: no, i want it above the text as it is verticaly but i want it centered horizontally. flm ;)

Comment: `.star` should be absolute positioned.. change to relative and add center block.

Comment: cant position it to relative bcz the parts r not styaing above each other and they get stacked. i want them to be above each other and than to animate them via js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this Html instead:

```
     <div>

            <div class="row">

           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 

                    <div class="star center-block">
                    </div>
                    <div class="moon center-block">
                    </div>
                    <div class="moon2 center-block">
                    </div>
           </div>

          </div>
 </div>


        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">  

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 

                <div class="logo-text">UMBRA</div>

           </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

          </div>

        </div>
```

And this css:

```
    .logo {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.star {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;


  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;

}

.moon {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -99px;


  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.2); */

}


.moon2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  top: -199px;

  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.2); */

}
.moon2:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(25,25,25,1)100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)80%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(25,25,25,1)100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)80%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(25,25,25,1)100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)80%);


}


.logo-text {
  display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Bicyclette-Regular";
  font-size: 40px;  
}

.logo-text2 {

  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Bicyclette-Regular';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #999;

}
```

Comment: u r putting the text in the same row as the circle. i want them to be in separate rows. i want the text to stay under the circle but both to be centered horizontally. i managed to center the text simply by adding text-align: center on css but i cant center the circle.

Comment: yes im working but i asked you before and you said you wanted aligned vertically in the middle. Let me a few minutes and i will edit my answer for you.

Comment: no, i want it horizontally aligned just above the text.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see it. Only thing you have to fix is the height of other circles because i dont know why are you using them but if u set it auto would be a fix.